# Initiate facebook like script several times

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, tumblr

I'm using infinite scroll on tumblr, and inside the elements i load at runtime i have a facebook like button. Everything works the first time i call the script, however, it seems as if i can't load it more than once, and therefore the elements created when scrolling wont have a working facebook button due to not existing when the script was loaded. Nothing happens if i do this after more content is loaded.

Looking at the script ( http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js ), it looks like the script will only run once per page, is there any way around this?

My code:

```
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];   
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.async=true;  
js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=484534104905547";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution for you.  The JavaScript SDK gives us a function called `FB.XFBML.parse`.

> **FB.XFBML.parse** - This function parses and renders XFBML markup in a document on the fly...

Once your infinite scroll function is called and you load more data, simply call this function again to render the new plugins.

To reparse the entire page, you can just call this function as-is -

```
  FB.XFBML.parse();
```

If you want to parse a specific element on your page, you can pass it to the function -

```
  FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('foo'));
```

---

#### Reference -

- [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)
- [FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/)

Comment: Sweet, everything runs now!
You saved my day Lix